# How to adjust the height of the dropdown of a <select> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<select>` which should load its options from the server when clicked. While trying to do so there was a small problem I couldn't get over which is that the height of the dropdown box wouldn't expand automatically when all the options are loaded. I tried to change the `size` of the select or click it twice and neither worked. Here's a simple simulation of what I'm talking about and the first time you click the select you'll see all the options are loaded but they're hidden by the insufficient height of the dropdown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script>
        var data = JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"EE&CS\",\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"Management\",\"id\":2},{\"name\":\"Subjects\",\"id\":3},{\"name\":\"Other\",\"id\":32},{\"name\":\"Test\",\"id\":33}]");
        window.onload = function () {
            var select = document.getElementById("select-test");
            select.onclick = function () {
                if (this.dataset.loaded === "0") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var subject = data[i];
                        select.appendChild(getNode("<option value=\"" + subject.id + "\">" + subject.name + "</option>"));
                    }
                    this.dataset.loaded = "1";
                    // select.size += data.length;
                    // this.click(); this.click();
                    // How to adjust the dropdown height to be exactly the total height of all options???
                }
            }
        };

        function getNode(str) {
            return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body.childNodes[0];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="select-test" data-loaded="0">
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose subject --</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are loading the items on click of the dropdown. You have already expanded the dropdown before the items load. If you click off it and back on it will be the correct size. The solution is to load the items before you click on the dropdown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script>
        var data = JSON.parse("[{\"name\":\"EE&CS\",\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"Management\",\"id\":2},{\"name\":\"Subjects\",\"id\":3},{\"name\":\"Other\",\"id\":32},{\"name\":\"Test\",\"id\":33}]");
        window.onload = function () {
            var select = document.getElementById("select-test");

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var subject = data[i];
                select.appendChild(getNode("<option value=\"" + subject.id + "\">" + subject.name + "</option>"));
            }
        };

        function getNode(str) {
            return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body.childNodes[0];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="select-test" data-loaded="0">
    <option value="" disabled selected>-- Choose subject --</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I need to load after clicking. Imagine you have several selects whose options are subsets of its previous select's selected option so when the previous selected option changes they need to refresh their options too, and that's when you need to click to make a refresh. Anyway, my problem is to change the height of the dropdown after clicking and loading.

Comment: You load the dependent options on change of the parent select, that is the standard way of doing things. I have never seen any site do it on click of the child.

Comment: Yes, I've done it by loading child options on change of parent option.